# How to edit a NuGet's package?

Tags: xamarin-forms-4

I want to edit Xamarin's community toolkit's camera view to record videos in 1280x720 or higher if not available, MP4 format with AAC audio(or anything that is supported by chrome)

I tried editing its source code, compiling and replacing the DLLs. So far I managed to change the resolution successfully, but it changed the audio codec to AMR.
I used this function to replace the GetMaxSize in Android/CameraFragment

```
ASize GetMiddleSize(ASize[]? imageSizes)
        {
            ASize? maxSize = null;
        long maxPixels = 0;
            var video = Array.Find(imageSizes, x => x.Height == 720);
            if (video != null)
            {
                return video;
            }
            else
            {
                if (imageSizes != null)
                {
                    var length = imageSizes.Length;
            return imageSizes[length / 2];
                }
            }
}
```